# Pyinstaller и Pyqt как впихнуть в приложение каhтинку которая используется в качестве иконки кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

Я создал приложение где впихиваю в кнопку изображение, я пытался найти решение моей проблемы, но каждый раз появлялись новые проблемы, до того что изображение перестаёт загружаться, до каких-то ошибок во время компиляции, пожалуйста! расскажите универсальный метод компиляции в exe приложение где используются картинки! Буду очень благодарен!
ps создавал с помощью qtDesigner

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

ison = ['qw.bmp', 'qx.bmp']

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(461, 448)
        self.MainWindow_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow_2.setObjectName("MainWindow_2")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.MainWindow_2)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 441, 351))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.Grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.Grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.Grid.setObjectName("Grid")
        self.Go = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.MainWindow_2)
        self.Go.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 71, 41))
        self.Go.setObjectName("Go")
        self.Go.clicked.connect(self.Begin)

    def Begin(self):
        for i in range(1,6):
            for j in range(1, 6):
                c = choice(ison) 
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('')
                button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(c))
                self.Grid.addWidget(button, i,j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>461</width>
    <height>448</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="MainWindow_2">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>441</width>
      <height>351</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="Grid"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Go">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>71</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Стартуем!</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: не хватает кода

Comment: добавил код, вообщем, мне просто нужно сделать работающий exe, в котором будут видны изображения qw.bmp и qx.bmp прошу прощения за возможно криво составленный вопрос :/

Comment: ну во первых, вам нужно прописать абсолютные пути до изображений, когда вы к ним обращаетесь, с помощью модуля os. что то вроде ```os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "image.jpg")```.

Comment: Во вторых включить изображения в скрипт сборки. Тут так же пишут об imageformats, но вы можете попробовать без него, если не получится, то добавить в проект https://coderoad.ru/5721953/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-pyqt-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Первое, что вы должны запомнить - `НИКОГДА` НЕ изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer. `НИКОГДА`. 2. Опубликуйте модуль `.ui`.

Comment: прошу прощения, я новичок, мало что понимаю, мне нужно залить куда-то файл ui, отправить на него ссылку? Просто там ещё есть лишние виджеты которые не совсем относятся к проблеме(    
 Вроде я не изменял модуль

Comment: и вот по поводу абсолютной ссылки, это способ как-то превратить в exe без помощи pyinstaller, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: нет,  не надо залить куда-то файл `ui` и отправлять на него ссылку. Добавьте его таким же образом как пример, который вы опубликовали.

Comment: добавил, убрал вроде всё что не относится к теме, у меня просто там другие виджеты, которые вроде не имеют значения

Comment: @opaopapa если вы используете qtdesigner, то почему вы просто не подключите иконку к кнопке с помощью ресурсов, он сам все упакует и вам не нужно будет париться из-за сборки

Comment: и нет, это не новый способ сборки без pyinstaller, так просто принято

Comment: все имеет значение, вы предоставили битый модуль `.ui`. Либо вы предоставите, то что у вас есть ничего не убирая или формируете новый `.ui` только с теми виджетами, которые вас интересуют.

Comment: @S.Nick ладно уже, видимо дело в том, что qt не подцепляет картинки в последствии, или при сборке, если нет, то значит он неправильно задает вопросы :)

Comment: да и предполагаю, что там qt выдал как обычно полотно в 3 листа в .ui . Правда для таких целей есть pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучший способ реализовать то, что вы хотите, это предварительно упаковать ваши картинки в ресурсы Qt Designer(такая панелька справа снизу)
[image: Qt Designer]

Добавьте категорию для ресурсов, добавьте внутрь ресурс, сохраните файлы в ui(включая файл ресурсов в qrc), скомпилируйте как обычно.
Подключение с использованием ресурсов:

```py
QtGui.QIcon(":/категория/имяизображения.формат")
```

Comment: Гигантское вам спасибо! Вы спасли меня! Хотелось бы добавить, что qrc файл в py файл превратить надо так: pyrcc5 -o название.py название.qrc  вот, большое вам ещё раз спасибо! надеюсь кто-то, кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой нашли решение.